# How to connect current measurement?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to run this DC simulation, but I cannot connect the current measurement block to the circuit!

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things:

1. The  black coloured source block that you have added is from Simscape Specialised library. Consider adding something from Simscape-> Sources library (ensure that your network is blue in colour)
2. Your model is missing a solver configuration block
3. Connecting a display to the network doesn't measure current, you need to add appropriate sensors to measure the quantity you want. For ex you measure current using a Current sensor, a voltage using Voltage sensor and so on

Fixing the above 3 should get you your output.